# GDB: format of backtrace command: frame line divided into several lines when running in another shell/ssh

Tags: shell, formatting, console, gdb, backtrace

When I run GDB with BACKTRACE command locally (Ubuntu 10.10) I am getting this output:

```
#0  0xb5f810db in ?? ()
#1  0x081a0b19 in CObject::Event (this=0xb1aa53d8, _t1=@0xbfd315ec, _t2=0xb1aa53d8, _t3=false) at moc_xreobject.cpp:96
#2  0x08157f24 in CSoundResource::ReportOpen (this=0xb60a31e8) at ../../src/sender/soundresource.cpp:203
#3  0x0818a38e in JavaScriptSoundObject::onOpen (this=0x8376d78, index=@0xbfd31698) at ../../src/sender/flashsounditem.cpp:264
```

When I run it over the same coredump remotely (SSH) on Ubuntu 9.04 box I am getting:

```
#0  0xb5f810db in ?? ()
#1  0x081a0b19 in CObject::Event (this=0xb1aa53d8, _t1=@0xbfd315ec, 
    _t2=0xb1aa53d8, _t3=false) at moc_xreobject.cpp:96
#2  0x08157f24 in CSoundResource::ReportOpen (this=0xb60a31e8)
    at ../../src/sender/soundresource.cpp:203
#3  0x0818a38e in JavaScriptSoundObject::onOpen (this=0x8376d78, 
    index=@0xbfd31698) at ../../src/sender/flashsounditem.cpp:264
```

Would appreciate any suggestion how to make it run consistently like the first sample. Does it have something to do with that remote shell settings or GDB itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like gdb is wrapping the output, possibly the terminal tells it a wrong size, so try:

```
set width 0
```

so that gdb doesn't wrap the output.